# Carlo Rovelli - Schrodinger's Cat

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedingers-cat

I am puzzled by the physicist Rovelli's take on the Schrodinger's Cat thought experiment.

Instead of the cat being dead or alive, he replaces the poison by a soporific. Instead of the possibility of the cat dying, there is the possibility of it falling asleep.

Why does he make the change? I don't it is out of political correctness.

Here is how I interpret his thought experiment. Please correct me if I am wrong.

The reason the cat goes to sleep, instead of dies, is that Rovelli wants the cat to be an observer. If the cat it still awake, then from its perspective it is awake. At the same time for the observer, who has still not opened the box, the cat is in a superposition of asleep/awake.

Rovelli with his RQM, relational quantum mechanics want's to make observations relative to different observers.

Seems very feeble to me. When the experimenter opens the box he will have the same reality as the cat.

I don't know why he didn't refer to the Wigner's Fiend thought experiment. Here it is the friend who conducts the experiment, and Wigner later opens the door to see if the friend is weeping over a dead cat, or rejoicing that the cat is still alive.

I learned about Rovelli's interpretation of QM from his latest book, "Helgoland".

I am keen to hear your thoughts about Rovelli's modification to the experiment, and his interpretation.

Comment: We expect questions to be reasonably self-contained, so it would be great if you could edit your question so that people who *haven't* read Helgoland can understand it, too.

Comment: I did explain his position, and actually people who haven't read Helgoland could still understand it. I don't see how I could actually make it clearer without quoting a page or two from the book. I could of course just have  written, "according to Rovelli...."

Comment: The cat is either awake or asleep, because Rovelli considers the original version of the experiment, in which it is killed, to be animal cruelty. This is more of an animal rights than a physics question.

Comment: I thought of that, but I am not sure. Anyway whether the cat is dead of sleeping there is still a question to be answered. It seems simpler to me that it is the poison releasing detector which collapsed the wave function. In the double slit experiment, are there no marks on the screen until the experimenter comes back to the lab to see them?

Comment: Rovelli explains the reason for his change in a footnote: “In the original version, the bottle contains not a sleeping gas but poison, and the cat did not fall asleep: it died. I prefer not to play around with the death of a cat.”

Comment: It is Winger's friend experiment, plain and simple.

Comment: @Anixx. I thought so. I wish he had written to that effect. Rovelli is not as precise and clear as he would like to think he is.

Comment: @gandalf. Yes now that is clear. It is also clear from subsequent reading via Google that the observer doesn't have to be conscious. A detector would do.

Comment: It seems that Rovelli posits an endless stream of superpositions. Would he affirm that every time before we discover something that we are dealing with a superposition?